# Oracle: MERGE INTO with invisible columns

Tags: oracle, merge, invisible

I have got an problem with ORA-00904: invalid identifier.

As example: 
I have a table created like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
    (
      COL_1     VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) NOT NULL,
      COL_2     VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
      COL_3     RAW(16) INVISIBLE DEFAULT SYS_GUID ()
    )
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST_TABLE_PK ON TEST_TABLE
    (COL_1);
```

A second table on a remote db (DBLINK: testdb) looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
  COL_1     VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  COL_2     VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST_TABLE_PK ON TEST_TABLE
    (COL_1);
```

In the next step I want to merge the data between the local and remote db with an merge into statement like this:

```
MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE@testdb target
        USING (SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE 
                WHERE COL_3 = '3F47613050860B4EE0539D0A10AC10B7') source
           ON (target.COL_1 = source.COL_1)
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
      UPDATE SET target.COL_2 = source.COL_2
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
      INSERT     (COL_1, COL_2)
          VALUES (source.COL_1, source.COL_2);
```

The merge into statement does not work, because of an ORA-00904: "A5".COL_3 invalid identifier. But the same merge into statement works fine if the COL_3 column is visible.
Where does the "A5" come from?
Whats the problem here? Does anyone have the same issues?

Oracle versions: The local db is 12cSE and the remote db is 11g.

Comment: what version(full version) of oracle?

Comment: The local db is 12cSE (12.1.0.1.0) and the remote db is 11g. Invisible columns are supported with oracle 12c+. The hidden column is only on the 12c db.

Comment: The problem is that the driving site of MERGE statement is Oracle 11 as you merge into remote table. So the semantics of the command is analyzed from Oracle 11 perspective.

Comment: @Husqvik It would explain it but I reproduced the same error on both Db being 12c. Seems like invisible columns even more invisible when database link is involved. So at this point, I can only suggest to make invisible column visible, do the merge and make it invisible again.

Comment: So, it seems to be an "issue" or an Oracle "feature" that is not allowed to merge invisible columns when an dblink is involved. @Nicholas thank you for testing it on oracle 12c. Or is it possible to give oralce an hint?

Comment: An second interesting phenomenon appears when you hide a column, then oracle removes the columns comments.

Comment: I don't have two independent instances but with linked CDB and PDB containers the case works. I also tested that just `SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 FROM TEST_TABLE@oracle12` from Oracle 11 throws invalid identifier on COL3.

Comment: @Husqvik I execute the merge statement on the 12c site. So, my select statement in the using case should be executed on the 12c site? The hidden column "COL_3" is nor updated or inserted on the 11g site.

Comment: The fact you execute the command against some instance doesn't mean that it's physically executed there when database links are involved. If you join local with remote tables Oracle decides which table will be transferred to which involved instance. The one chosen for execution is called driving site and can be set using driving_site hint. But as far as I know it affects JOINs only so in your case it's not relevant. Didn't play that much with DB links but it seems in DML case is the driving site the local instance to the updated table.

Comment: So the current solution is to set the hidden columns to visible.

Comment: Do you still get the error when you do a `USING (SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM TEST_TABLE` rather than `USING (SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE` ?

Comment: Not tested yet, but maybe this will work, if the col_3 is selected too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your *source* table select, by name COL_1 and COL_2.
The key is to *get rid of* `SELECT * from`

```
MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE@testdb target
        USING (SELECT COL_1,COL_2 FROM TEST_TABLE 
                WHERE COL_3 = '3F47613050860B4EE0539D0A10AC10B7') source
           ON (target.COL_1 = source.COL_1)
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
      UPDATE SET target.COL_2 = source.COL_2
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
      INSERT     (COL_1, COL_2)
          VALUES (source.COL_1, source.COL_2);
```